# Custom logic for NHibernate if entity is not found

Tags: nhibernate

Is there any way to put custom logic when referenced entity is not found by id?

The problem: users fields store AD logins and reference table Users. The table contains only active users (it is a customer's policy). And when we open a record with inactive user we get EntityNotFoundException. We want to return a dummy User object filled by it's login.

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could map the reference to the User with `not-found="ignore"`. Missing users will then show up as null in the association property which you could handle yourself.

Class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private string _userLogin;
    private User _user;

    public virtual User User
    {
        get
        {
            if (_user == null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_userLogin))
            {
                return new User(_userLogin); // Dummy User
            }
            return _user;
        }
        set
        {
            _user = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<property name="_userLogin" column="user_login" access="field" insert="false" update="false" />
<many-to-one name="_user" column="user_login" access="field" not-found="ignore" />
```

Comment: But, will we get access to the reference value?

Comment: @MichaelGurenkov What do you mean? If there is no row in the Users table there will also be no User object, it will be null instead. You have to create a dummy User object yourself in that case.

Comment: I need a user login to create dummy User object :-)

Comment: But, nevertheless, is there a way to solve that on Interceptor level?

Comment: @MichaelGurenkov No idea, I've never used Interceptors myself.